# What do you do if ./configure complains about a missing header file

Tags: c, gcc, autoconf, google-chrome-os

So I recently ran into a problem trying to build [a program](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn) using under chromeos (chronos).

I cloned the repository and as instructed ran `./autogen.sh`. No problems this far.

However, when I ran `./configure` I got the following message:

```
checking arpa/inet.h usability... no
```

This told me that the configure script wasn't able to find the `arpa/inet.h` header file, however it didn't tell me where it was looking for.

Given that a regular chrome installation is pretty unusual, I wasn't surprised with getting some kind of error, but the message wasn't helpful at all as to how to fix it.

So my questions where:

1. Were was `./configure` looking for the headers?
2. Did I have them somewhere it wasn't finding it?
3. How do I make it find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question I looked into the `configure` file itself. It was a shell script so I could just replace append  `-x` to `#! /bin/sh` at the very top to make shell echo every command it ran.

That turned out to be unmaneagable since `configure` was huge and there was a lot of jumping between functions. So I wondered what was that magical `configure` script and what was that `./autogen.sh` script that I ran earlier and how could I make it run in a more *verbose* manner. Turns out that autogen is a description that's read by [autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) and the result is written as a `configure` file. Turn's out there's a [documentation page](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Debugging.html) explaining how to debug the resulting script.

As instructed I have wrapped the call that checked for `arpa/inet.h` in the `configure` script with `set -x` and `set +x`.

I couldn't find any `find` or anything similar in it but I saw some `gcc -E test.c` here and there. I guessed that `autoconf` was creating a simple `C` file that contained an `#include` directive and then `autoconf` parsed the output of `gcc` to tell if the header could be found at all.

So my next test was to create a simple test file that did exactly that:

```cpp
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

I saved the above content as a `C` file and tried compiling it with `gcc -E test.c > /dev/null`. The output was this:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/socket.h:33,
                 from /usr/local/include/netinet/in.h:23,
                 from /usr/local/include/arpa/inet.h:22,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/local/include/bits/socket.h:390:10: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory
  390 | #include <asm/socket.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

That told me that one of the dependencies of `arpa/inet.h` was importing `asm/socket.h` and failing to find it.

After reaching this far I wanted to make sure that `gcc` was looking in the right places for the headers before proceeding any further. Fortunately there's a [page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path) in the documentation that explains that.

Running,

```sh
cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null
```

I obtained the follwing in the output:

```
...
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
...
```

`/usr/local/include` was indeed where my header files were. And answering the second question, no I didn't have `asm/socket.h` somewhere else. Googling I found that it was supposed to be included in the linux source header files, normally found in a distribution package.

As I was using [chromebrew](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew) I needed to run `crew install linuxheaders` to get them.

And that was how I answered the third question. By installing the packages `configure` was able to run and generate the make files and I was able to build and install `openfortivpn`.

Hopefully this will be useful to someone (probably myself) in the future.

Comment: You could just run `sh -x configure` instead of modifying the script.   Also, the configure script leaves a file **config.log** that shows the files it tests for and, if the test fails, the C code of the test program that resulted in the error.  The log isn't what I'd call easy to read, but probably tells you as much as you'd find out by experimenting.  :-)

Comment: That was my first thought, but as you mention it was super hard to find what I was looking for. Since `configure` is a script that you can generate as many times as you want, there is little reason not to modify it to help you with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

> Were was ./configure looking for the headers?

`./configure` script invoked the compiler, which in turn was searching for the include path. Compiler include paths are system and environment dependent - refer to your compiler and system documentation.

Most (if not all nowadays) Linux distributions follow [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html), where system C header files are located inside `/usr/include` and additionally administrator C header files are installed to `/usr/local/include`. Most probably compiler adds its own custom additional paths - for gcc most importantly [C_INCLUDE_PATH](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables) environment variable.

> Did I have them somewhere it wasn't finding it?

Even if you "have" it (the file itself), most probably it's not compatible with your system and the symbols do not exist in C standard library implementation. Most probably, the compiler is already configured to find the file in the system by your system provider, so if the file does not exist, most probably it's just not there.

> How do I make it find them?

It is a broad question. If a system does not provide a specific interface, it most probably does not exist. It's a chance it can be installed using system-specific tools or a system-specific package manager. Or you can write your own implementation of the interface provided by the header and provide the interface and put the header you developed in `/usr/local/include`.

`arpa/inet.h` is part of [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/arpa_inet.h.html). You can provide your own implementation of symbols exposed in the header and configure `./configure` script to find it with options or environment variables.